# Windows WSL 2 can't ping host machine

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just upgraded to Windows WSL 2 today. The problem is I can't ping the host machine.

I got the IP for the host machine from /etc/resolv.conf.

From WSL 2 Ubuntu console:

- I can ping 8.8.8.8.
- I can not ping 172.17.12.65 (host machine).
- I can not ping www.google.com

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Seems strange you can ping your DNS server hosted by Google but are unable to ping a different google domain.  What IP address does Windows believe your host machine is assigned to?  (172.17.xxx.xxx) is not a typical intranet address.

Comment: Try to run WSL as admin. Also check in `/etc/resolv.conf` the `nameserver` line.

Comment: Yes this is an issue. MS will make this as bridged mode in future.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, do you know the issue tracker? I have gone back to WSL 1, since I can't use VcXsrv because of this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Some indication from this github thread suggests that it may be simply the firewall on your Windows host blocking the traffic...

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4192#issuecomment-503804455

Quoting xtremeperf:

> "Actually... you're probably being blocked by the Windows firewall, as
>   WSL2 is considered to be on a "Public Network". You'll need to open
>   these ports manually on the Windows firewall because they are not yet
>   automatically configured upon installation in this early beta
>   release."

Like harrymc and andoryu- said, check the content of "/etc/resolv.conf" to check the WSL2 IP. AFAIK it should be the one to unblock.

Unfortunately the virtual switch adapter connection profile for WSL2 is "Public" by default, and cannot be set to "Private" permanently unless you can assign a VLAN ID to the adapter, but I don't currently know of way to do that with Microsoft's Virtual Machine Platform feature, which is what I am using. Hopefully Microsoft will allow this to be easily changed in a future release. I haven't yet researched if it is possible to run WSL2 using Microsoft's Hypervisor Platform feature only. If someone knows, that may be helpful.

Although it may not be desirable, you can simply allow inbound ICMP echo traffic on the host firewall for "Public" profiles. An example using Windows Defender:

1. Launch Windows Defender Firewall via Control Panel.
2. Select "Advanced Settings" (on the left)
3. Right-click "Inbound Rules" and choose "New Rule..."
4. Choose "Custom" and click "Next"
5. Choose "All Programs" and click "Next"
6. Select the "ICMPv4" protocol type, then click "Customize..."
7. Choose "Specific ICMP types" and check "Echo Request" and click "OK", then "Next"
8. Choose "Any IP Address" or add specific addresses as you require for Local and Remote (in your case ), and click "Next"
9. Choose "Allow the connection" and click "Next"
10. Choose Public, Domain and Private and click "Next"
11. Give the rule a meaningful name and click "Finish"

Answer (score 2):

Ping to the host machine is blocked by default by the Windows firewall.

[The answer by Johan van Tonder](https://superuser.com/a/1496354/61370) is a little bit too complicated. You do not need to create a new rule because rules for ICMP echo are already there. They are just disabled. See [comment on GitHub issue: WSL2 unable to ping host machine #4171](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4171#issuecomment-929858850).

### Enable firewall rules

In Windows run elevated PowerShell and execute (not necessary to enable both ICMPv4 and ICMPv6):

```powershell
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'Virtual Machine Monitoring (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)'
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'Virtual Machine Monitoring (Echo Request - ICMPv6-In)'
```

### Test ping to host

```bash
~$ ip route show default
default via 172.26.224.1 dev eth0
~$ ping -c1 172.26.224.1
PING 172.26.224.1 (172.26.224.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.26.224.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.375 ms

--- 172.26.224.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.375/0.375/0.375/0.000 ms
```

---

Inability to ping `www.google.com` is a different problem which can depend on failing DNS resolution or something else.

Comment: This worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only answering as I bumped into the same issue.

First, unlikey one comment implied, 172.16.*.* - 172.31.*.* is reserved private IP Address, so I'm pretty sure 172.17.12.65 is valid for your host.

I found ipconfig in cmd.exe reveals that nameserver address in /etc/resolv.conf 
is actually the address of vEthernet(WSL).

Maybe the issue has something to do with hyper-v ethernet adaptor?

Comment: Also ran into this issue. WSL 1 allow me perfectly fine to access from my phone within the same network, but once I convert the instance to WSL 2, Hyper-V seems to kick in and I can't access it anymore from the network.

Answer (score 1):

Allow ping (ICMP packets) into your Windows firewall, as follows:

In Windows, press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key --> search for "cmd" --> right-click the "Command Prompt" and go to "Run as administrator" --> run the following commands as an administrator:

```bash
# Allow IPv4 ICMP ping packets in through the Windows firewall
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMPv4 Allow Ping Requests" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

Source: see "Method 3" here: https://www.wintips.org/how-to-allow-ping-in-windows-firewall/

Now you can ping Windows from WSL! It works for me, at least.

If you want to undo that, blocking ping packets into Windows again, run this:

```bash
# Block incoming ping packets again
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMPv4 Allow Ping Requests" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=block
```

Note:

In Windows, see your interfaces and IP addresses with `ipconfig`. In WSL or Linux, see all of your interfaces and IP addresses with `ip address`. I don't recommend `ifconfig` in Linux anymore because I think it's deprecated, and if you have multiple IP addresses assigned to a single interface adapter in Linux, `ifconfig` will only show the *first* one, whereas `ip address` (or `ip a` for short) will show *all* of them.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420

- Find out your router gateway
- Create `/etc/wsl.conf` in WSL with the following content:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

- Shutdown WSL in Powershell `wsl --shutdown`
- `sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver gateway_ip" > /etc/resolv.conf'`